# DataWriter.StoreAsync() not available on WASM

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I am having an issue downloading images from my website with my Uno App on the **WASM** Platform.
**It works against UWP**.  My code is:

```
StorageFile imageFile = await SelectedFolder.CreateFileAsync($"{item.picturekey}.jpg",
    Overwrite ? CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting : CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
if (imageFile != null)
{                        
    byte[] imageArray = await DataService.GetImage(item.picturekey, item.hiresurl);
    if (imageArray != null)
    {
        var stream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream))
            {
                if (imageArray != null)
                {
                        sb.AppendLine(this.DownloadStatus);
                        await writer.StoreAsync();
                        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I test against wasm, I receive:

```
fail: Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter[0]
    The member DataWriter.DataWriter(IOutputStream outputStream) is not implemented in Uno.
```

My try-catch give me:
System.NullReferenceException: Arg_NullReferenceException at Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter.WriteBytes[Byte[] value) ... line 62

```
I have checked to be sure, imageArray.Length > 0, so I am not passing in a null.

I assume that it is really supported in Uno for UWP and not WASM, is there a work-around?

Thanks, any suggestions would be helpful.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataWriter` [is not implemented](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/56d3ba98ee6cab055dc8d7c4941ce4494e20e946/src/Uno.UWP/Generated/3.0.0.0/Windows.Storage.Streams/DataWriter.cs#L15-L18) for streams at this point.

You should be able to use [`.AsStreamForWrite()` extension method](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/56d3ba98ee6cab055dc8d7c4941ce4494e20e946/src/Uno.UWP/System.IO/WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.cs#L88) and use a .NET [`StreamWriter` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0).

Uno Platform generally chooses to implement WinRT APIs based on the presence of an equivalent API in the .NET APIs, which is why some portions like this one are not yet available.